# Do all observers agree on the sequence of the formation of several black holes?

Tags: black-holes, relativity

If black holes must be in black holes in all reference frames, does the formation and or evaporation of SEVERAL black holes occur in the same order in all reference frames ie if one observer determines that black hole A formed, then black hole B, then black hole C, would any observers in any reference frame also be able to derive the same sequence for the formation of the black holes (or for the evaporation)?

Comment: I'm far from my area of competence, but ... doesn't the processes of formation of a physical (as opposed to eternal) black hole take an arbitrarily long period of time from the POV of a distant observer?

Comment: @dmckee, those are my initial thoughts too.

Comment: Consider the world line of an observer freely falling into black hole B.  This observer ceases to exist in finite proper time and, as has been discussed here, will not receive light from events arbitrarily far in the future before encountering B's singularity.